# What is the sum of sum of digits of $4444^{4444^{4444}}$?

Tags: number-theory

A [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169797/write-down-the-sum-of-sum-of-sum-of-digits-of-44444444) asked about the sum of sum of sum of digits of $4444^{4444}$. The solution there works mainly because the number chosen is small enough for the sum of sum of sum to be equal to the repeated sum: i.e. if we sum digits further, the result does not change. Since finding repeated sums of digits is just a matter of elementary number theory, this solves the problem.

It seems the following question might be much harder: what is the sum of sum of digits of $$4444^{4444^{4444}}?$$
In other words, let $f:\Bbb N_0\to\Bbb N_0$ be the function defined by $f(n)=\textrm{sum of decimal digits of }n$.

> What is the value of $f\left(f\left(4444^{4444^{4444}}\right)\right)$?

In this question, we have not yet reached a single-digit number, which at least seems to make it much harder.

Some estimates: the number of decimal digits of $4444^{4444^{4444}}$ is equal to $$\left\lfloor\log_{10}4444^{4444^{4444}}\right\rfloor+1,$$ which implies $$f\left(4444^{4444^{4444}}\right)\le9\left(\log_{10}4444^{4444^{4444}}+1\right).$$

Next, the number of digits of this last number is at most $$\left\lfloor\log_{10}\left(9\left(\log_{10}4444^{4444^{4444}}+1\right)\right)\right\rfloor+1,$$ which is $16213$, according to [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Log%5B10,9%284444%5E4444%20Log%5B10,4444%5D%2b1%29%5D). Therefore, $$f\left(f\left(4444^{4444^{4444}}\right)\right)\leq9\cdot16213=145917.$$

So the number we are looking for has at most $6$ digits. This makes it very feasible to express in decimal notation, but possibly hard to find.

We might be further interested in numbers like $$f\left(f\left(f\left(4444^{4444^{4444^{4444}}}\right)\right)\right),$$ so a related question would be:

> Is there any hope for a general method of evaluating such functions or is the behaviour of the $k$-fold composition $f^k$ completely chaotic?

Comment: smells like an advanced application of the chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: @Auke: May I ask, which moduli do you smell?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: mod 10, mod 100, mod 1000, etc.

Comment: @Anke: The Chinese remainder theorem doesn't work very well for moduli that are multiples of each other.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.math.wayne.edu/~boehm/archives/W12/Prob10SOL.pdf) ?  I think one can use the same thread of idea and extend it recursively to a higher notion.

Comment: @Iyengar: Interesting ... I don't really see how to extend this, though, since the function is only periodic for small values and otherwise seems kind of chaotic ... If you have a concrete idea how to do it, I'd be happy to know.

Comment: @Iyengar:  however it is incorrect when $f(f(f(n)))$ has more than one digit, which is the case here.  The conjecture is that it has only one digit for all $n$, which we know to be false.

Comment: oh dear this is 5 years old none the less, fantastic question that is undoubtedly on my aspirations for explicitly being able to answer, but i will say, it is just an example of a broad range of problems that need solving, I have previously been referred to material regarding something called the "Knuth up arrow" and did trying to take everything I read on board, but my die hard formalism just would not accept it, and I don't think I will be truly satisfied until I understand the iteration of exponentiation to the same extent as I do addition and multiplication

Answer (score 7):

You can find an upper bound for it even without using computer or any calculator:
$$
f(N) < 9 (4444^{4444} \times \log_{10} 4444 + 1) < 9 \times 4 \times 4444^{4444} + 9
$$
$$
f(f(N)) < 9 ( \log_{10}9 + \log_{10}4 + 4444 \log_{10}4444 + 1) < 9 (3 + 4444 \times 4) = 9 \times 17779 = 160011
$$

so
$$ f(f(N))<160011  $$
this is a large range but it can be smaller with calculator. (Note that you should have computed base 10 logarithm instead of natural logarithm)

the range consists of 160011 numbers, and by knowing the reminder of 9, only 17,779 numbers are left, and answer is one of them.

Of course this is not an exact answer, but it is straightforward!

**Edit: I just misused a formula which is about something different, sorry for that!**

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I edited my question. I'm not sure I understand your lower bound, though. Where did you get $f(N)> 9(4444^{4444} + log_{10}4444 -2) > 9 \times 3 \times 4444^{4444} - 18$ from?

Comment: As I'm looking at it again, I see that I just misused something I had read somewhere (which is about  **probability** and digit count of a normal number will be around that) and even, what I have used is not that formula, so I was totally wrong, sorry about that!