# the sum of digits

Tags: number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Write down the sum of sum of  sum of digits of $4444^{4444}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169797/write-down-the-sum-of-sum-of-sum-of-digits-of-44444444)

If we write $ 4444^{4444}$ in decimal form .Then the sum of digits is equal to :$A$ .If we assume that: $B$ is the sum of digits :$A$ .How to find the sum of digits :$B$

Comment: http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.08/h/shivdeep1.html

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169857/what-is-the-sum-of-sum-of-digits-of-444444444444

Comment: Also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169797/write-down-the-sum-of-sum-of-sum-of-digits-of-44444444?lq=1