# If $d(n)$ is the sum of digits of n, find $d(d(d(n)))$ of $n=4444^{4444}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $d(n)$ is the sum of digits of n, find $d(d(d(n)))$ of $n=4444^{4444}$.

My attempt:

$4444^{4444}<10000^{4444}$

Now, $\max d(10000^{4444})<9\times 17776$

Again, $\max d(159984)\le 45$

Again $\max d(45)\le 12$

So, $\max d(d(d(n)))\le 12$.

Now, what am I supposed to do? Please help.

Comment: Well, there's this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+digits+of+4444%5E4444. Can you find any pattern on $d(4444^k)$ or $d(k^k)$ you might use?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169857/what-is-the-sum-of-sum-of-digits-of-444444444444

Comment: @IanColey what is meant by the base? I am not clear about it yet...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169797/write-down-the-sum-of-sum-of-sum-of-digits-of-44444444

Comment: This is IMO $1975$ Q$4$

Comment: Do you know about digital roots?

Comment: @MarkBennet might know the matter inside, but do not know about the title of the topic, so, highly probable that I do not know about it.

Comment: @MarkBennet thank you for your help...

Comment: @Henry thank you for the reference.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thank you for the reference...

Comment: The sum of the digits of a number is $9n+r$ for some integer $n$ where $r$ is the remainder on division by $9$. Iterating the process eventually gets you to $r$ - except multiples of $9$ go to $9$.

Comment: @MarkBennet Okay, thank you for the help.