# Applying the sum-of-digits operation to $4444^{4444}$ three times

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$A$ is the sum of the digits of $4444^{4444}$. $B$ is the sum of the digits of $A$. Then what will be the sum of digits of $B$?

I found this in the Suggestion paper of Mathematical Tripos Exam of Cambridge

Comment: This is from an IMO

Comment: Found it here! http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1975_IMO_Problems/Problem_4

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169797/write-down-the-sum-of-sum-of-sum-of-digits-of-44444444?rq=1

Comment: answer is $7$...

Comment: Those are not bogus comment; they will give you the answer, if you just bother to follow the links and read...

Comment: I know what you want, but I don't think that "sum of digits" is the correct expression. Maybe "reduced sum of digits" or "iterated sum of digits". For example, the sum of the digits of $4444$ is $16$. What you want is $7$.