# Sum of the digits of the sum of the digits of the sum of the digits of $4444^{4444}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am told this may be connected to the properties of numbers modulo 9.

Thank you.

Comment: You could look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169797/write-down-the-sum-of-sum-of-sum-of-digits-of-44444444

Comment: This is the most famous IMO problem I think

Comment: Do you mean, performing "sum of digits" until reaching a single digit? Or do you mean, performing "sum of digits" $3$ times?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, repeatedly summing the digits of a positive integer N eventually yields the residue class of N mod 9, except that when N is divisible by 9 the final sum of digits is 9 rather than 0.

So the first task is is compute the class of $4444^{4444}$ mod 9.

When computing the class of a power $r^s$ mod 9, note that the 6th power of r is 1 mod 9 provided that r is not divisible by 3.  This allows us to reduce s modulo 6 before we begin.  4444 is not divisible by 3, and 4444 is 4 mod 6 so $4444^{4444} \equiv 4444^4$ mod 9.

To compute this class mod 9, we can begin by reducing that remaining 4444 mod 9.  4444 is 7 mod 9 so $4444^{4444}\equiv 7^4$ mod 9.

$7^4$ is 49 times 49, and 49 is 4 mod 9.  We have $7^4 \equiv 4^2$ mod 9, and $4^2$ is 7 mod 9.

So $4444^{4444}\equiv 7$ mod 9, and the sum of digits you seek is 7

Comment: It's also necessary to verify that the process terminates after three steps, e.g. using logs.